# What is the shortcut for opening something like Gui terminal in debian?

Tags: debian, terminal

Yes, im very aware that the title is simply put stupidly but i run out of ideas
the thing is, friend of mine showed me way (probably shortcut but i forgot)it basically get rid of all gui, just fullscreene black terminal with green input line

as i saied i have no idea what it was, how did i done it but it maybe had to do something wit F2 but im not sure, any help would be usefull

Comment: Do you mean switching to a virtual console with CTRL+ALT+F1 (or F2, F3 etc.)?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167386/how-to-switch-between-tty-and-xorg-session

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.